# Binary search method needs to be more efficient

Tags: java, boolean, binary-search

```
   int i = 0;
    int finalVal = 0;
    while (i < this.maxQuestions) {
        if (this.isGreaterThan(average(lowerLimit, upperLimit))) {
            lowerLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
            finalVal = upperLimit;
        } else {
            upperLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
            finalVal = lowerLimit;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("The number you picked was: " + finalVal);
```

Basically I'm doing a binary search using a boolean `isGreaterThan,` which asks *is the number greater than x?* and you can answer yes or no. The array of values from lowerLimit to upperLimit is cut in half each iteration, by making the previous average become the new lowerLimit or upperLimit.

The problem is that once it narrows the array down to just two or three values, it will ask *is the number greater than x?* for the same number multiple times, such as:

`Is it greater than 56?` yes

`Is it greater than 57?` no

`Is it greater than 56?` no

The number is 56.

I'm pretty sure that it's because the average is rounded down as an int. It works perfectly up until the end, I just can't figure out how to alleviate this last little problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have had a base case where lowerLimit == upperLimit and if it is just return that number and if not call isGreaterThan function.